# Can I use a different graphical driver while booting, and the proprietery NVIDIA driver once my computer has started?

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics, nouveau

I have a bit of a problem in that as I am booting my PC, the boot screen isn't exactly pretty because I am using the proprietary NVIDIA drivers.

I am wondering if there is a method to use the VESA drivers while my computer boots to get the pretty splash screen (Either that, or make NVIDIA display the pretty splash screen -- I assume it is because of Kernel Mode Setting that it doesn't work properly)

Any advise is much appreciated!

(Note: I cannot use the nouveau drivers because they are faulty with my video card, making Ubuntu particularly difficult to install [NVIDIA GTX 580])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a workaround to what you are asking but it is as close as you are going to get
This is a old guide but still works as of 13.04
http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Fix-the-Big-and-Ugly-Plymouth-Logo-in-Ubuntu-10-04-140810.shtml
I have a [NVIDIA GTX 550 TI] if you are wondering